# MouseDoubleClick event missing from DataGrid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I'm am writing a page in Silverlight and when I use a DataGrid element it is missing the MouseDoubleClick event from its' events. It's not in the event list and when i wirte it manualy i get and error saying:
"The property MouseDoubleClick was not found in type DataGrid"
Anyone know what the problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: There's no Double-Click event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events(v=vs.95).aspx However, if you google around you may find alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClickCount` property of [MouseButtonEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in the event [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) can help you...